# MySQL: Error 1114. table is full. can't drop the table

Tags: mysql, import, csv

I am trying to load a single 28GB csv file (257 million rows) into MySQL database for almost a week. However I got Error 1114 while loading after 4730 seconds (or more/less, different in every execution). I have tried to find the solution here and already adjusted the `my.ini` as following:

```
max_allowed_packet = 1024M
max_heap_table_size = 1024M
tmp_table_size = 1024M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2048M
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:1024M:autoextend
innodb_log_buffer_size = 1024M
innodb_log_file_size = 1024M
innodb_file_per_table = 1
```

But the error still occurred. The server logs just showed `The table xxx is full`. The second problem is that I cannot drop this corrupted, full table. The server connection broken everytime when I want to drop the table (Lost connection). I am wondering how can I modify my `my.ini` better to deal with this big csv file and drop the broken table?

My RAM is 4G and the harddrive still has enough space (162G, so I don't think this is problem). My session settings are: keep-alive interval / read time out / time out are all 99999 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

wouldn't that whole file needed to be loaded into RAM first? I would recommend splitting it up into chunks not bigger that 3GB each before submitting them.

Also, [this post](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/11/03/choosing-innodb_buffer_pool_size/) suggests that "setting buffer pool a bit larger than your database size" was a good practice.

It looks to me that your whole set up is not quite up to the task.

Comment: thank you so much! I am now splitting my data, and also change `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2048M` to `32768M`. Hoping that it works well later!

Comment: Sounds like you have too many indexes on that huge table.